# How can i OverwritePermissions in a discord channel for the authors from a List?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, permissions, discord.py

I'm trying to make a discord bot with **discord.py** and i got a command in it which appends the **author.id** s into a List called **Memberson**..
`Memberson = []`
I need to make a command which creates a channel with Overwritepermission `read_message: True` for the authors in the List.. How can i do it? Should i need to comprehise the list with a **dict**? If yes, how can i do it? Pls help..
I tried like this But it ended in an error because Memberson isnt an attribute of guild :(

````
overwrites = {
    guild.Memberson: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=True),
    guild.me: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=True)
}

channel = await guild.create_text_channel('test', overwrites=overwrites)```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I managed this with `channel.set_permissions`.

Try this;

```py
    overwrites = {
        ctx.guild.me: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=True),
        ctx.guild.default_role: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=False)
    }
    channel = await ctx.guild.create_text_channel('test', overwrites=overwrites)

    for i in range(len(Memberson)):
        user = bot.get_user(Memberson[i])
        await channel.set_permissions(user, read_messages=True)
```

Comment: OMG!! THANK YOU SO MUCH!! FINALLY GOT THE SOLUTION

Answer (score 0):

Edit:
Seems like overwrites don't work with a list.
Look at my other answer I managed to do it :>

Comment: I did it but it gives me 'unhashable type: list' error